# Button attribute backgroundSize, backgroudRepeat, backgroundSize don't work

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I use nativescript-vue.
Could help me. *Button*  attributes: **backgroundSize**, **backgroudRepeat**, **backgroundSize** don't work

```html
<Button
backgroundRepeat="no-repeat" 
backgroundSize="contain"
backgroundPosition="center" 
 />
```

[reproduce bug playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=9rqSC3&v=26)

But if you set them through a class or style attribute, then it works.

Thank's

Comment: It seems to work, what is the output you are expecting? Between, using `Image` component may be suitable for the kind of images you are loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

backgroundSize, backgroudRepeat and backgroundSize are **not** the button attributes. If you check the [Button](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_button_.button) class, only [background](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_button_.button#background), backgroundColor and backgroundImage are available as properties.

You can set them using CSS only.